# Can Windows Phone 8.1 application work in Phone 8.0?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to work application, which developed for 8.1 OS, in Phone which have 8.0 OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. You could only deploy 8.1 apps on a device which is updated to 8.1. It's just a matter of updating the 8 OS. But after the 8.1 update you could still deploy WP8 apps too.

For more:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642082(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)